# Создание и управление структурой файлов наподобие git без добавления самих файлов в репозиторий

Tags: git

Необходимо синхронизировать 2 огромных файловых хранилища, в каждом из них могут обновляться данные (удаляться, добавляться файлы), насколько корректно будет использовать git для этой цели (не создастся ли репозиторий размером с это хранилище?)?
Существуют ли другие программные решения для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: не известно, то такое огромное (для кого то 100мб уже много, а кому то пару терабайт мелочь), но вряд ли гит будет для этого подходящей идеей. Скорее всего Вам нужен rsync.

Comment: Именно что создастся репозиторий размером с хранилище. Более того, он будет хранить все версии файлов (т.е. даже после удаления файлы в репозитории будут занимать место), плюс в репозитории будет храниться еще дополнительная информация, плюс еще копию этого репозитрия (со всеми этими дополнительными файлами) нужно будет хранить на этих 2 хостах.

Comment: мне когда то похожее нужно было сделать. я делал так. на каждом хосте запустил `find . -exec md5sum {} \;` и получил список файлов и их хеши. Если хеши совпадают, скорее всего это одинаковые файлы. Дальше с помощью сортировки и дифф утилиты был получен список разницы. У меня он был небольшой и нужные файлы были перетянуты в почти ручном режиме (на основе списка был сгенерирован баш скрипт, где scp просто перетаскивал нужные файлы)

Comment: @KoVadim так это вы вручную сделали то, что rsync делает :)

Comment: приблизительно. Но я тогда был молод, а гугл ещё не был так популярен. Альтависта было наше все

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вам нужно синхронизировать в обе стоороны? Попробую назвать пару готовых продуктов, которые можно поставить и настроить.

Думаю, что "на поверхности" лежит решение, основанное на [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/). Эта штука вполне способна "пережевать" большие директории, работает она на основе хещей, и до тех пор, пока не произошло ситуации, что на двух концах по разному изменился один и тот же файл - должна работать вполне надёжно.

Вторым кандидатом - из готовых решений - я бы назвал [seafile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/). Он тоже хорошо работает на больших объёмах, умеет передавать по сети только diff файла в случае его изменения.

я бы предложил использовать rsync, но я не понимаю, как запустить схему, в которой синхроонизация будет происходить в обе стороны. И, самое главное, как сделать, чтобы эта схема не зацикливалась - там ведь надо будет включить два rsync'а.

Возможно, мой ответ не полный, и кто тоо добавит еще что то - в другом ответе, или в комментариях.

Успехов вам!